# Stored Procedure not inserting records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that attempts to insert records from a function into a table.  When I run the stored procedure, it completes successfully, but does not insert any records into the table.  If I highlight the Insert code, it works.  I am quite new to all this and would appreciate any help please.

```
The Stored Procedure is:

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataQualityDashboard_UpdatePart1] 
    AS

    DECLARE @StartDate date
    DECLARE @EndDate date

    SET @StartDate = '2017-01-01'
    SET @EndDate = '2017-01-31'

    Insert into [iCS.Warehouse3].[dbo].[DashboardData] 

    Select 

    MetricID
    , FirstDateofMonth
    , Numerator
    , Denominator

    From [iCS.Warehouse3].[KPI].[DataQualityEthnicityOutpatientsWCFT]  
    (@StartDate, @EndDate) 

    Commit;
```

The Function it calls upon is [iCS.Warehouse3].[KPI].[DataQualityEthnicityOutpatientsWCFT], which is below.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [KPI].[DataQualityEthnicityOutpatientsWCFT]   
(
  @StartDate date
, @EndDate date
)

RETURNS TABLE
  AS
  RETURN
  (
    WITH EthnicityOutpatients (XCN, EthnicGroup, FirstDateOfMonth, MetricID)
    AS
    (
      SELECT
        o.XCN
       ,p.EthnicGroup
       ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) as FirstDateOfMonth
       ,1 as MetricID

      FROM [iCS.Warehouse3].[OP].[Appointments] o

      Inner Join [iCS.Warehouse3].[lk].[Patient] p
        on o.[XCN] = p.[XCN]

      Inner Join [iCS.Warehouse3].[lk].[Calendar] cal
        on o.AppointmentDate = cal.TheDate

      Inner Join [iCS.Warehouse3].[dbo].[LocationLK] l
        on o.ClinicLocation = l.Location

       WHERE o.AppointmentDate >= @StartDate and o.AppointmentDate <= @EndDate
         and o.AppointmentStatus = 'A'
         and o.Specialty not in ('NR', 'NPH')
         and l.WCFTorSatellite = 'WCFT'
     )
  SELECT
    FirstDateOfMonth
  , MetricID
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN EthnicGroup is null THEN 1 END) as Numerator
  , COUNT (XCN) as Denominator
  FROM EthnicityOutpatients 
  GROUP BY 
    FirstDateOfMonth
  , MetricID
  )
```

The table it should be inserting records into is [iCS.Warehouse3].[dbo].[DashboardData].

It has four fields: MetricID, Date, Numerator and Denominator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated please.
Thanks in advance, Andrew.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: How about a commit?

Comment: Thank you jarlh.  Sorry, but what do you mean by tag the dbms?

Comment: Thank you Piotr.  What is a commit?

Comment: well I suppose that you are using microsoft which uses t-sql which stands for transact-structured query language, where transact stands for transaction xD
And commit; is what puts data from transaction into the database for others to see.
So just try to put `commit;` after the insert in stored procedure

Comment: If this works I'll put it in an answer

Comment: Thanks Pitor.  Yes, I am using Microsoft and TSQL.  I tried adding commit; but it still didn't insert any records.

Comment: Does the query `SELECT
 o.XCN
,p.EthnicGroup
,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) as FirstDateOfMonth
,1 as MetricID` etc return any rows?

Comment: And you have  `Select 

    MetricID
    , FirstDateofMonth
    , Numerator
    , Denominator` but fields in returned table are defined as `XCN, EthnicGroup, FirstDateOfMonth, MetricID`. Perhaps consider changing names in upper select?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with brackets. The names are ok. Check if query returns anything

Comment: Thanks Piotr.  The query does return a count.  Everything about it works apart from the stored procedure not inserting the count into the table.

Comment: could you edit the post so we see where you put your `commit;`?

Comment: The Dashboard table how many columns does it have? Perhaps you need to specify the columns

Comment: Hi Kostis.  There are 4 columns in the dashboard table.  The Function returns 4 columns too.

Comment: in t-sql you don't need a `commit` unless there is a `begin tran`. So that's a red herring.

Comment: How do you run the stored procedure? If you are just running the code you posted then you are only saving the stored procedure. To run it use `EXEC DataQualityDashboard_UpdatePart1`

Comment: Also, you should never run an `insert` without a column list. Also there is no reason to put that query into a function. You could impact performance.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I have tried adding EXEC DataQualityDashboard_UpdatePart1  to another stored procedure, but that didn't work.  I am hoping to build a SSRS report from this that other users can view, so I need it to update when they run the SSRS report.

Comment: I have put the query into a function, because I am going to be adding about 40 other KPIs to the dashbaord, so i think was thinking separate functions may help?

Comment: Do you have any log from executuion? Any error reports?

Comment: Sorry Piotr.  Not sure where to get the log or error reports from?  The Stored Procedure says it runs successfully.  It doesn't bring any errors up.

Comment: Very rare occasion but is there any chance to have a before insert trigger in that table that checks whether to add or update if similar record exists?

Comment: Thanks Kostis.  The table is currently empty, as I have deleted all records from it.  I will eventually add something to delete similar records before inserting new ones.  Firstly, I am just trying to get the insert to work.

Comment: if you run the query " Select 
* From [iCS.Warehouse3].[KPI].[DataQualityEthnicityOutpatientsWCFT] ('2017-01-01', '2017-01-31') " do you get any results?

Comment: Hi Kostis, I do get results if I run that:

Comment: " I have tried adding EXEC DataQualityDashboard_UpdatePart1 to another stored procedure". NO. Just run that directly in SQL Server  Management Studio. **We still haven't ascertained that you have actually managed to run the SP yet**. and _please_ do not write 'didn't work'. Do some investigation - did it not run? not return records?